# How to toggle images

Tags: javascript

I am a programming fool,

All I need is to be able to toggle two images, one which acts as the 'up state' of a button and then 'onclick' the second image appears and remains until it is clicked again whereby it is replaced by the the 'upstate image'.

Please don't mock me for this pitifull attempt which fails miserably. Here is my code.

```
function change() {

   if (window.document.pic.src == "imgd1.svg"){
       window.document.pic.src ="imgd1over.svg";
   }
   else if(window.document.pic.src == "imgd1over.svg"){
       window.document.pic.src ="imgd1.svg";
   }

   <img src ="imgd1.svg" name ="pic" id = "test" onclick ="change()"/>
```

Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9xp7y5ka/).

```
function change(image) {
   if (image.src.indexOf("imgd1.svg") > -1){
       image.src ="imgd1over.svg";
   }
   else{
       image.src ="imgd1.svg";
   }
}
```

In the fiddle case the `image.src` wasn't just the image's name, but the full url: `http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/imgd1.svg`. So I have used [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to check if the image's source constains the string you want.

Besides, I have changed the way `change()` function references to the image:

```
 <img src ="imgd1.svg" name ="pic" id = "test" onclick ="change(this)"/>
```

Using `change(this)` will set the own image as the first parameter of the event, so you don't need to get it in the `window` object or event with [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

```
function change() {
    var image = document.getElementById("test");
    if (image.src.indexOf("imgd1.svg") > -1 ){
        image.src = "imgd1over.svg";
    }
    else if(image.src.indexOf("imgd1over.svg") > -1 ){
        image.src = "imgd1.svg";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
<img src ="imgd1.svg" name="pic" onclick="change();"/>

<script>
    function change() {
       if (window.document.pic.src == "imgd1.svg"){
           window.document.pic.src ="imgd1over.svg";
       }
       else if(window.document.pic.src == "imgd1over.svg"){
           window.document.pic.src ="imgd1.svg";
       }
    }
<script>
```

**See the full demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/jswsze5q/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
   function change() {
       var img1 = "imgd1.svg",
           img2 = "imgd1over.svg";
       var imgElement = document.getElementById('test');       
       imgElement.src = (imgElement.src === img1)? img2 : img1;
    }
</script>
<img src="imgd1.svg" id="test" onclick="change();"/>
```

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guspersson/s8qLg7ur/)

Answer (score -2):

Try using Jquery

```
var flag = 0;
function change(){
  if(flag){
    $("#img").attr("src","img1.png");
    flag = 0;
  }
  else{
    $("#img").attr("src","img2.png");
    flag = 1;
  }
}
```

Simplest toggle option
where variable `flag` acts as flag which detects which image is active
`img` is the `id` of image control.

Code to include Jquery from google CDN

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Added Jquery URL @DontVoteMeDown

Comment: Doesn't metter. OP isn't using jQuery at all.